# How to change cell background color and add text(from selected button) in full calendar Cell by Clicking Button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, fullcalendar

I am new to full calendar with java script concept.

I am having a working full calendar. I am having two button Working Day and Off day. What I need is, My date cells in calendar must be selectable only after I choose any of those 2 buttons. Lets say, If I choose Working Day button, then the cells I choose must change its background color and the text Working Day must be added to those selected cells.

Question2: Also, I need to add those selected date to my datatable.. that too working, but how to pass Text from button to td?

Codes:
Full Calendar Design:

```
<div class="box box-primary">
<div class="box-body no-padding">
<!-- THE CALENDAR -->
<div id="calendar_full"></div>
</div>
<!-- /.box-body -->
</div>
```

Script to load Calendar alone:

```
 <script>
    $(function () {
   var t = $('#Selection').DataTable();
        var counter = 1;
        var date = new Date()
        var d = date.getDate(),
            m = date.getMonth(),
            y = date.getFullYear()

        $('#calendar_full').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title'
                //right: 'month' //agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,

                dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
                    //var D = moment(date);
                    t.row.add([
                        counter,
                        date.format('dddd,MMMM DD,YYYY'),
                        'testing'
                    ]).draw(false);

                    counter++;

                    cell.css("background-color", "teal");
                }
        })
    })
    </script>
```

This makes my calendar looks properly and data also added to data table.

But for my buttons I tried only 1 button  as of now:
Script as follows:

```
 <script>
  $(function () {
  var t = $('#CalendarSelection').DataTable();
        var counter = 1;
        var date = new Date()
        var d = date.getDate(),
            m = date.getMonth(),
            y = date.getFullYear()

        $('#calendar_full').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title'
                //right: 'month' //agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
        })
        $("#btnWorkingDay").select(function () {
            $('#calendar_full').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title'
                    //right: 'month' //agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,

                dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
                    t.row.add([
                        counter,
                        date.format('dddd,MMMM DD,YYYY'),
                        'testing'
                    ]).draw(false);

                    counter++;

                    cell.css("background-color", "teal");
                },

            })

        });
    })
    </script>
```

btnWorkingDay is my button name. The date cells must change to teal color and text must added to that cell as Working Day, after I clicked my btnWorkingDay button only. My script not working. Is there any way to fix this.
Kindly help.TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set it up as follow:

```js
$(function(){
  var t = $('#CalendarSelection').DataTable();
  var counter = 1;
  var date = new Date()
  var d = date.getDate(),
      m = date.getMonth(),
      y = date.getFullYear()

  $("#btnWorkingDay").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    $("#btnOffDay").removeClass("selected");
  });
  $("#btnOffDay").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    $("#btnWorkingDay").removeClass("selected");
  });
  $('#calendar_full').fullCalendar({
    plugins: [ 'interaction' ],
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title'
      //right: 'month' //agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {

      if(!$("#btnWorkingDay").hasClass("selected") && !$("#btnOffDay").hasClass("selected"))
        return;

      var cell = $(this);
      
      if($("#btnWorkingDay").hasClass("selected")){
        var backgroundColour = 'blue';
        var description = 'Working Day';
      }else if($("#btnOffDay").hasClass("selected")){
        var backgroundColour = 'red';
        var description = 'Off Day';
      }
      
      cell
        .css('background-color', backgroundColour)
        .text(description);
      
      if($('tr[data-date="'+cell.data('date')+'"]').length > 0) {
        var data = t.row( $('tr[data-date="'+cell.data('date')+'"]') ).data();
        
        t
          .row($('tr[data-date="'+cell.data('date')+'"]'))
          .data([
            data[0],
            data[1],
            cell.text()
          ]);
          
          return;
      }
      
      rowNode = t.row.add([
          counter,
          date.format('dddd,MMMM DD,YYYY'),
          cell.text()
      ])
        .draw()
        .node();
      
      $(rowNode).attr('data-date', cell.data('date'));   

      counter++;       
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.js"></script>

<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="box box-primary">
<div class="box-body no-padding">
<!-- THE CALENDAR -->
<div id="calendar_full"></div>
</div>
<!-- /.box-body -->
</div>


<button type="button" id="btnWorkingDay">
Working Day
</button>

<button type="button" id="btnOffDay">
Off Day
</button>

<div>
  <table id="CalendarSelection">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>date</th>
        <th>description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

As you can see it now lets you to add date you select to datatable within the label of being working day or off day and based on the buttons (working day - off day) you select it colours the date selected and sets the label.

I hope this helps and if you are happy with it accept this as the answer.

Comment: Your answer works like awesome, but still got few flaws for my expectation.. cell must be selectable only after any of two buttons got selected..but from your answer, when I click any cell that automatically added to my datatable.. but I want only buttonwise selected cells and dates to be added to my data table... how to correct this..

Comment: but its a timely help, as I was completely fed up, just by working on this fullcalendar... Thank u once again.. CAn u plz explain me the script a bit.. SO that I can learn by myself..

Comment: Also,If I changed my selected working day to off day, my datatable description only needs to update from working day to off day.. but as of now, I got 2 data's added individually in both working day and off day under same date..

Comment: @riya I updated the code and if you check it again you will see it will update the row in table rather than adding a new one. I hope this helps.

Comment: your updated one works fine for me thank you so much. Is there any way to control full calendar to display selected year only.. I already tried valid range and visible range.. but after dec nxt year jan came and vice versa.. **Is there any site that clearly and easily teaches this full calendar.. I need lot to do with it**

Comment: @Riya Well the best site to learn how to use full calendar plugin is to read their own documentation. You could find their documentation here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/4270163/mohammad-bagheri  can you plz explain this line `($('tr[data-date="'+cell.data('date')+'"]').length > 0)`, as I am using same function in 2 places, it works on one place and not on another place, so I need to clear this line...

Comment: regarding this: ($('tr[data-date="'+cell.data('date')+'"]').length > 0)
it is for checking if a date selected and already added to the table. I have added date data attribute to each row in the table having the value of selected date. So using this we can check which dates are selected and added to the table to be able to remove or amend them in the future if needed. I hope this explains things for you.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/4270163/mohammad-bagheri.. I understand. The same code I used in 2places. When I debug I found out,conditon is same at both places, but, At one place, its not working.. thats Y I asked u explanation.

Comment: @Riya Well possibly you have an issue in your code somewhere which is making that bit not to work. Without seeing the code I cannot really help and give you more info on that. :(

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/4270163/mohammad-bagheri    In this fiddle I added my code, but my fiddle is not working, but I gave tha fiddle link for my code reference.. jsfiddle.net/jso2hbtp .. If can, Kindly help.